# Excel VBA issue with table generation in MSWord

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Trying to generate a code to produce multiple tables that take the first colum plus one other column of data from the original excel file and generate tables in MS word. The below code allows generation of the tables required but after each table it is then deleted and the next table is created in its place how can i fix this to add a line break or spacing etc so that all the tables are displayed one after the other?

```
Sub ExportToWord()
    Dim objWordApp As Object
    Dim objWordDoc As Object
    Dim objExcelSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Create a new instance of Word application
    Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWordApp.Visible = True ' Make Word visible
    
    ' Create a new document
    Set objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Add
    
    ' Excel sheet export
    Set objExcelSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' rows with data in column A
    lastRow = objExcelSheet.Cells(objExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'columns with data in row 1
    lastcolumn = objExcelSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
    ' Set the initial range
    Set rng = objExcelSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
    ' create a table for column A plus i
    For i = 2 To lastcolumn
        ' Set the table range (first column + current additional column)
        Set rng = Union(rng, objExcelSheet.Range(objExcelSheet.Cells(1, i), objExcelSheet.Cells(lastRow, i)))
        
        ' Add a table to the Word document
        tableRowCount = lastRow ' Use lastRow as the initial row count
        Set objTable = objWordDoc.Tables.Add(objWordDoc.Range, tableRowCount, 2)
        
        ' Copy data from Excel to Word table
        For j = 1 To tableRowCount
            objTable.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = objExcelSheet.Cells(j, 1).Text
            objTable.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = objExcelSheet.Cells(j, i).Text
        Next j
    
    objWordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    objWordApp.Selection.typeparagraph
    
    
       Next i
    
    ' Clean up
    Set objTable = Nothing
    Set objWordDoc = Nothing
    Set objWordApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

.....................

Comment: Is the code executed once for every table that you want to add to the MS Word Document?

Comment: So at the moment my example excel table contains ten rows and 8 columns( 1 headings column plus 7 others). The Macro would ideally be run once and generate 7 tables one after the other with column 1 in each and one of the other 7 columns in each (using a loop?)

Answer (score 1):

- `objWordDoc.Tables.Add(objWordDoc.Range, tableRowCount, 2)` overwrites the content with the new table.
- Credit to @***Timothy Rylatt*** : `objWordDoc.Characters.Last` is more efficient than `Selection`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWord()
    Dim objWordApp As Object
    Dim objWordDoc As Object
    Dim objExcelSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objTable As Object, tableRowCount As Long
    Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const wdStory = 6
    ' Create a new instance of Word application
    On Error Resume Next
        Set objWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If objWordApp is Nothing Then Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objWordApp is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    objWordApp.Visible = True ' Make Word visible
    ' Create a new document
    Set objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Add
    ' Excel sheet export
    Set objExcelSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' rows with data in column A
    lastRow = objExcelSheet.Cells(objExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'columns with data in row 1
    lastcolumn = objExcelSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Set the initial range
    Set rng = objExcelSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    ' create a table for column A plus i
    For i = 2 To lastcolumn
        ' Add a table to the Word document
        Set objTable = objWordDoc.Tables.Add(objWordDoc.Characters.Last, lastRow, 2)
        ' Set objTable = objWordDoc.Tables.Add(objWordApp.Selection.Range, lastRow, 2)
        ' Copy data from Excel to Word table
        For j = 1 To lastRow
            objTable.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = objExcelSheet.Cells(j, 1).Text
            objTable.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = objExcelSheet.Cells(j, i).Text
        Next j
        objWordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        ' objWordApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory
    Next i
    ' Clean up
    Set objTable = Nothing
    Set objWordDoc = Nothing
    Set objWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Selection` use `objWordDoc.Characters.Last` as it is more efficient.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I've updated the code as your suggestion. Thanks